# Unable to use json.loads on boto3.client.get_batch_predictions()

Tags: json, django, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-machine-learning

I'm getting the following error when trying to parse a json response

> expected string or buffer

Within my Django model I have the following:

```
def get_batch_prediction(self):
    client = boto3.client('machinelearning', region_name=settings.region, aws_access_key_id=settings.aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=settings.aws_secret_access_key)
    return client.get_batch_prediction(
        BatchPredictionId=str(self.id)
        )
```

I then call it like so

```
batch = BatchPrediction.objects.get(id=batch_id)
response = batch.get_batch_prediction()
response = json.loads(response)
```

I know the response is `json` so I expected this to change it to a dictionary but, instead, I get the error above.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [boto3 docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/machinelearning.html#MachineLearning.Client.get_batch_prediction) suggest that `get_batch_prediction` returns a dictionary not a string. You shouldn't have to use `json.loads()`.